# Vertices not showing in vert select mode, and I cannot manipulate or transform anything

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

So, I'm in vert select mode, and I cannot select anything except for pressing **A**, which selects everything. Also when I'm in vert select mode, the edges are bolded like if I was in edge select mode. Also, when I select stuff, I cannot transform stuff. I cannot bevel, inset, shear, move, rotate, scale, you name it I can't do it. Important: I'm fairly advanced with blender and I have tried the basics so don't hit me with stuff like "did you try using G keybind to move" or "did you try using the tool in the toolbar". The issue seems to arise when I go into vert paint mode, as I'm using vertex paint for a bevel radius for the bevel shader. I'm using the shader because I'm baking directly from the low poly (traditional bake style can be a real bitch for me). This has happened on multiple computers, if I append the object or copy it to another file, the issue persists.
Edit: This error message comes up right before the issue appears as soon as I go into vert paint, and also I can't see the verts in vert paint mode: Tool 'builtin.select_box' not found for space 'VIEW_3D'.
[image: Important to note I am in vertex select mode]

Comment: New mutation: When I go into sculpt mode, the mesh disappears

Comment: Solved! I went into edit mode, then to vert select mode, then pressed alt h to unhide everything and that solved my problem